# Windows Azure Media Services dynamic packaging - how to change stream order in HLS?

Tags: azure, stream, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services, m3u8

(TLDR summary: **I need a way to adjust the *initial* stream in the m3u8 file produced by Azure Media Services dynamic packaging, on a per-request basis.** )

Currently I have a lot of assets which I use dynamic packaging to access.  I am using Adaptive Bit Rate streaming, so the asset container contains 8 streams of various quality, and the dynamic packaging is putting together an m3u8 playlist using a url ending in "{...}.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)"  .  This does ALMOST exactly what I need.

I am encoding with custom XML which is basically the H264AdaptiveBitrateMP4Set720p configuration, but with auto rotation enabled.  This has encoded files of bitrates from as high as 3400 down to 400 (plus 2 audio files).

Here is the problem:
I am delivering to an iOS app via adaptive bitrate streaming.  Many videos are 5-15 seconds.  It usually takes 10 seconds of playback at the initial bitrate to auto-adjust to a stream appropriate to the connection.  However, because most videos are so short, the majority of every playback is at extremely low quality, with no way for users to stream the higher quality version even when on fast connections.

I've determined that this is because iOS automatically takes the first stream listed from the m3u8 file as its initial quality.  Azure Media Services dynamic packaging puts the lowest bitrate stream first in the m3u8 list.  Therefore, the device always starts playback of the lowest quality stream.  In our use case, this can be problematic.

The solution I want to take is to put some intelligence in the client about guessing at the initial speed desired (device on wifi could start at higher if not highest quality, device on cell can start at lower or lowest, and we can monitor and adjust initial bitrate based on last detected speed/quality.

**To accomplish that, I need a way to adjust the *initial* stream in the m3u8 file produced by Azure Media Services dynamic packaging, on a per-request basis.**  Apple proposes having multiple master files, but this isn't DIRECTLY possible with dynamic packaging, but it seems to be capable of the idea abstractly.  However, I have been trying to figure out HOW to pass in url criteria to select the initial somehow, and the closest I have found is to create a filter (e.g. .ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl, filter=MyFilter) )... however, that seems to only allow you to limit the streams available, not simply re-order them (or really, just move a specific one to the top based on some criteria).  I'm SOOO close to getting what I need, but am missing some key detail.

I'm curious if it is possible and I'm just missing it, or if it is a limitation I'll have to find another solution around?  I could fall back to static packaging (which would be a pain to update all the existing content), but beyond the tedious conversion, it is apparently deprecated and will be turned off soon, so that may not even be a real option.

Thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!

(Update 2016-01-20 to add clarity):
Basically, this is an example of the m3u8 file result from the HLS dynamic packaging of one of my videos:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="AAC_und_ch2_96kbps",URI="QualityLevels(93571)/Manifest(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps,format=m3u8-aapl)"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="AAC_und_ch2_56kbps",DEFAULT=YES,URI="QualityLevels(53646)/Manifest(AAC_und_ch2_56kbps,format=m3u8-aapl)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=508030,RESOLUTION=240x180,CODECS="avc1.4d400d,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(387555)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=508030,RESOLUTION=240x180,CODECS="avc1.4d400d",URI="QualityLevels(387555)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=762407,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(636456)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=762407,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d4015",URI="QualityLevels(636456)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1104186,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(970878)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1104186,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401e",URI="QualityLevels(970878)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1603625,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(1459566)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1603625,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e",URI="QualityLevels(1459566)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2316919,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(2157505)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2316919,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e",URI="QualityLevels(2157505)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3444678,RESOLUTION=960x720,CODECS="avc1.4d4020,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(3260988)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3444678,RESOLUTION=960x720,CODECS="avc1.4d4020",URI="QualityLevels(3260988)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=62986,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(53646)/Manifest(AAC_und_ch2_56kbps,format=m3u8-aapl)
```

And I want to move one of the mid-quality streams to the top of that list (PER request.. i.e. devices on cell should use the above list, but devices on wireless should use this list):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="AAC_und_ch2_96kbps",URI="QualityLevels(93571)/Manifest(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps,format=m3u8-aapl)"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="AAC_und_ch2_56kbps",DEFAULT=YES,URI="QualityLevels(53646)/Manifest(AAC_und_ch2_56kbps,format=m3u8-aapl)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1104186,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(970878)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1104186,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401e",URI="QualityLevels(970878)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=508030,RESOLUTION=240x180,CODECS="avc1.4d400d,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(387555)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=508030,RESOLUTION=240x180,CODECS="avc1.4d400d",URI="QualityLevels(387555)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=762407,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(636456)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=762407,RESOLUTION=480x360,CODECS="avc1.4d4015",URI="QualityLevels(636456)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1603625,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(1459566)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1603625,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e",URI="QualityLevels(1459566)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2316919,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(2157505)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2316919,RESOLUTION=720x540,CODECS="avc1.4d401e",URI="QualityLevels(2157505)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3444678,RESOLUTION=960x720,CODECS="avc1.4d4020,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(3260988)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3444678,RESOLUTION=960x720,CODECS="avc1.4d4020",URI="QualityLevels(3260988)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=62986,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
QualityLevels(53646)/Manifest(AAC_und_ch2_56kbps,format=m3u8-aapl)
```

Note how these are essentially the SAME lists, except in the second one, the first STREAM listed is the 1104186 bitrate one, where in the second, it is the higher 508030 bitrate one, which iOS assumes is the initial quality (which it will upgrade or degrade from).  This way, short 6 second videos will not be insanely poor quality on high-speed connections... ideally, the device could note which bitrate it was last capable of and request an even higher initial (but still have the full list in the m3u8 so it could degrade as needed)

Comment: Any framework you are using to play the azure urls . How to make it play with AVPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restrict track? Or you could use AMP to set different heuristic profile: either fast start or high quality. Please refer to the samples here: https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_heuristicsProfile.html.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: That sounds promising, but the linked video is a general azure media services marketing spot rather than anything related to heuristics profiles (your link seems good, but the video on the page doesn't seem to be the one it intends to present).  I will do some searching to try to find more information or documentation, since this sounds exactly like what I am trying to do (based on title alone, at least).  Any idea where it might be documented, since I've failed to find reference so far?  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, after posting that, it occurred to me what the page actually was... out of context, I was thinking the video was the content, but really, the video was just what the container was pointing at.. the sample was the javascript.

So that said, no, that doesn't help... this would work through the javascript/html5 player, but does not help me on the iOS side... all I provide the iOS client is a link to an m3u8 file for HLS, and to do this I use Media Services' dynamic packaging.  I can set up a filter to limit the available streams, but this prevents downgrading below that limit, so doesn't fit

Comment: Hi, the player will retrieve a HLS if you play it using iPhone. The streaming URL comes from Azure Media Services, and the stream can be dynamically packaged into DASH, HLS or Smooth Streaming. When you use an iPhone browser to watch this content, player will pull the stream in HLS playlist format, and you will see HLS coming.

Comment: Yes, as noted in the original question, I have all of that working.  I am using Dynamic Packaging to get an HLS m3u8 file.  My problem is that iOS picks the first stream in the created m3u8 the initial stream quality, but I do NOT WANT the first stream to be the lowest quality all of the time, especially if the device is on wifi.  I want to define one of the mid-level streams to show up first (i.e. I just want to re-order them so the top one is different), but all I've found is filters which let me drop streams from the list. meaning no downgrading to them dynamically, which isn't what we want

Comment: I've added a quick update with exact output from Media Services to demonstrate the issue and ideal solution

Comment: Hi, I am checking with the team on this topic.